# Who participated in my poll (Google Forms)

Tags: google-forms

Is there a way to find out who voted on my Google Forms poll, given that I required login when created the poll?

Also, on the flip side of the coin, is there a way to authorize only defined users to be allowed to vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there's no way.  Google's [help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/139706?hl=en) says

> Please note that while users will be asked to log in to their Google
>   Account in order to access and fill out the form, their actual
>   usernames will not be recorded.

Some alternative approaches (taken from [here](http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.co.uk/2015/01/make-google-forms-from-unique-people-only.html)):

- You could make completing the form "inviation only" and email
  people a unique code that they have to input, then you don't take account
  of any responses that don't have a valid code that you issued.  (They may be in the results - you just ignore them.)
- If your form is made with a Google Apps user-account, rather than a
  standard Google account, then you have an option to limit a Google
  Form to only accept responses from users who are in your domain - and
  if you do this, the responses-sheet records the person's username as
  well.